# Route 53 Domain works on some devices, and sometimes only works on incognito, why is this?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-route53

**Context**

I have a site hosted statically on S3, with a custom domain moved from Wix to Route 53.
The name servers in the records match the registered domains, and have an A type alias that matches the name of the bucket, and an SOA. These were set up days ago so should be working by now.

**Problem**

When tested on 3 macs and a phone (always Chrome), it always connects on the phone and 1 mac, never connects on another, and only connects in incognito on the last, or 5/8.

**Error**

DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN (server IP address could not be found)

I've exhausted my limited knowledge of the issue so any insight is welcome.

Comment: This means its takes time to update DNS entry to all ISPs

Comment: I'm facing a very similar problem. The site works flawlessly when originating from all ip addresses except my home ip. It only works from my laptop's Firefox, the browser I used to configure AWS. I tried other browsers on the same laptop and no luck. But if I connect through VPN it works everywhere. I thought Firefox might be caching the site, but I cleared cache and history, used in private mode, and it still works. So at this point I guess it's due to DNS replication, some AWS security I enabled inadvertently, or some feature only supported in Firefox I'm not aware. My setup was yesterday.